# What is apache htaccess configuration to require authentication for all except for these URLs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What is the htaccess lines/config I would require to ensure that all parts of my site (files & URLs) are protected by authentication, EXCEPT for a given limited set of URLs. For example all except "/api/.*" if this makes sense.

The actually authentication could be like the below, but it's how I wrap this in the directives...

```
AuthName "Dialog prompt" AuthType 
Basic AuthUserFile
/home/site/.htpasswd Require
valid-user
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to work:

```
AuthUserFile /home/.htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
authtype Basic
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
SetEnvIf request_uri "/api/" allow_all
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=allow_all
```

Comment: To allow multiple url's just add an extra "SetEnvIf request_uri "/blah/" allow_all"

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`SetEnvIf`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) and [`<IfDefine>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ifdefine):

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/api/ no_auth_req
# If no_auth_req is NOT defined then require authentication
<IfDefine !no_auth_req>
    AuthName "Dialog prompt"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /home/site/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</IfDefine>
```

Comment: Thanks - can I ask if there was more than one URL I didn't want protected what the syntax would look like for this?

Comment: @Greg: Adjust the regular expression pattern or use another `SetEnvIf` directive.

Comment: actually I can't get this working & I see a link to someone saying the same ?  http://perplexed.co.uk/543_apache_setenvif_cant_pass_variables_to_ifdefine.htm